# Get some values from the table by selecting

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table:

```
| id   | Number      |Address 
| -----| ------------|-----------
| 1    | 0           |   NULL   
| 1    | 1           |   NULL   
| 1    | 2           |   50       
| 1    | 3           |   NULL     
| 2    | 0           |   10       
| 3    | 1           |   30       
| 3    | 2           |   20       
| 3    | 3           |   20       
| 4    | 0           |   75       
| 4    | 1           |   22       
| 4    | 2           |   30     
| 5    | 0           |   NULL
```

I need to get: the NUMBER of the last ADDRESS change for each ID.
I wrote this select:

```
select  dh.id, dh.number from table dh where dh = 
(select max(min(t.history)) from  table t where  t.id = dh.id group by t.address)
```

But this select not correctly handling the case when the address first changed, and then changed to the previous value. For example id=1: group by return:

```
| Number |
| -------- | 
| NULL   | 
| 50  |
```

I have been thinking about this select for several days, and I will be happy to receive any help.

Comment: What is the result that you want?  Do you want the row with the maximum `number` for each `id`?  So for the `id` of 1, you'd get a `number` of 3 and an `address` of `null`?

Comment: No, I need to get not just the maximum number, but the number at which the address was last changed. For example, id=3, number = 2

Comment: That may be very clear to you but I'm afraid that it isn't very clear to me.  What for you defines when the address last changed?  What is the result that you want?

Comment: I'm not sure either of what the expected output should look like. Could you please give us a hint on what the expected output is?

Comment: There is a large table that stores changes in many parameters. When you change any of the parameters, a line with a new number is added, but it is important for me to track the last change of address.

Comment: Using the example table from the question, I need to get: id=1, number = 3; id = 2, number = 0; id= 3, number=2; id=4, number = 2; id = 5, number = 0

Comment: Why don't you just use a MAX(Number) and GROUP BY id? If you don't select the Address column, that will give you the desired output.

Comment: Because, for example, with id=3, max(number) = 3, but the address changed when number = 2

Comment: In that case, are NULLs considered a change for your case? It's probably a window function problem, but would like to have that clear beforehand :D

Comment: Yes, a change to NULL is considered a change.

Comment: Any change of address is important to me. The query I wrote works in some cases. But it doesn't work if the address was changed to another one and then changed back. In this case, the number of the very first change is displayed. I've been sitting with this for a few days now, I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my question myself, if anyone needs it, my solution:

```
select * from table dh1 where dh1.number = (
  select max(x.number)
    from (
    select 
      dh2.id, dh2.number, dh2.address, lag(dh2.address) over(order by dh2.number asc) as prev
      from table dh2 where dh1.id=dh2.id 
    ) x  
    where NVL(x.address, 0) <> NVL(x.prev, 0) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()` -- twice:

```
select t.id, min(number)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by number desc) as seqnum1,
             row_number() over (partition by id, address order by number desc) as seqnum2
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum1 = seqnum2
group by id;
```

What this does is enumerate the rows by `number` in descending order:

- Once per `id`.
- Once per `id` and address.

These values are the same only when the value is `1`, which is the most recent address in the data.  Then aggregation pulls back the earliest row in this group.